# Repair for 5th Generation Kindle that is not charging

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

I believe the problem is a loose connection where the power cord plugs in.  For several months, I had to jiggle the cord to get the charging light to come on, but now that no longer works and the light will not come on at all.  The battery was replaced several months ago, so I know that's not the issue.  Would appreciate any recommendations for companies who can make these kinds of repairs or directions on how to fix it myself.

Comment: If it's the charger cord that's broken, it will be easier to fix! Have you tried using a different charger cord?